# Is $\{f':f\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})\}$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

I know that $C_c^1(\mathbb{R})$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$, but I cant prove that whether $\{f':f\in C^1_c(\mathbb{R})\}$ is dense in $C_c(\mathbb{R})$ or not.

Comment: What do you mean by dense? What topology are you considering? In any case, the real problem is probably in the fact that $\int f' =0$ for $f \in C^1_c$.

Comment: Yes, your point is not only very helpful for me, but it also gives the answer to my question. The set is not dense in $C_c$ in uniform topology. Thank you very much.